# Geometry that change?

Tags: geometry

Let us consider a water tub full of water , if any drop falls on it the circles are formed , and the circumference of the  circles  goes on increasing as they move away from there origin and there frequency goes on decreasing , is there any direct relation between them , the one way  I knew is to use the Calculus rate of change but any other way to find?

Comment: Calculus is often defined to be an extension of geometry concerning change.

Comment: Sir , without the help of calculus is this possible?

Comment: First of all, this is more of a physics question, not mathetics, as the answer depends on the physical properties of the water. it is certainly not geometry. Second, the frequency - which is how many waves pass a point in each second - does not decrease, as this would require the waves to move faster as they grew bigger. However, the *amplitude* of the waves decreases. Third, the propagation of waves obeys physical laws that are expressed in terms of calculus. You can solve those equations to get algebraic relations between circumference and amplitude, but at its heart, it is still calculus.